# PHP градиентная прозрачность копируемых изображений

Tags: php

Как пересохранить изображение с изменением размера на php и сохранением прозрачности градиента

Comment: Прозрачность в png с градиентом сделал, но теперь прозрачность в гиф сохраняется в зеленом цвете. Почему и как поправить?

Comment: Вопрос был про одно, а теперь в комментарии вы пытаетесь задать другой близкий к нему вопрос. На SO принято 1) публиковать ответ на собственный вопрос, если разобрались сами, 2) создавать новую тему на новый вопрос

Comment: Подсказка про _второй_ вопрос: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecolortransparent.php#104554